# Oracle - how to create view with user personalised data

Tags: oracle

How to create a view that stores the data only for logged user:
this does not work: Query rewrite not allowed on SYS relations"

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW UserPerspective 
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE AS
      SELECT * FROM EMP e, DEPT d, Salgrade s
      WHERE e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO
        AND e.ENAME like (SELECT User FROM Dual)
        AND e.Sal BETWEEN s.Losal AND s.Hisal
;
```

looks like I can't use (SELECT User FROM Dual) in view... How to do it correctly :

```
AND e.ENAME like (SELECT User FROM Dual)
```

Comment: MATERIALIZED means that Oracle creates an up to date copy of the result of the SELECT statement.  It can't do that because `User` changes from time to time.  It only keeps one copy, and isn't smart enough to keep one for each user.

Comment: @WW What you say sounds reasonable, but Oracle allows `user` in a materialized view, see my answer. Just not with query rewrite. I am unsure what the materialized view with `user` means.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance That seems strange. Which user would that be?  Is it materializing the user that ran the update statement, or the one that owns the materialized view?

Answer (score 2):

You can reference `USER` in a view, like so (note, dropping `Salgrade` because I don't have that table.):

```
CREATE VIEW V AS
SELECT e.EMPNO, e.ENAME, e.JOB, e.MGR, e.HIREDATE
   , e.SAL, e.COMM, e.DEPTNO, d.DNAME, d.LOC
FROM EMP e
INNER JOIN DEPT d ON e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO
WHERE e.ENAME = USER;
```

And in a materialized view likes so:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV AS
SELECT e.EMPNO, e.ENAME, e.JOB, e.MGR, e.HIREDATE
   , e.SAL, e.COMM, e.DEPTNO, d.DNAME, d.LOC
FROM EMP e
INNER JOIN DEPT d ON e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO
WHERE e.ENAME = USER;
```

But you cannot reference `USER` in a materialized view with query rewrite enabled:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MVEQR
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE AS
SELECT e.EMPNO, e.ENAME, e.JOB, e.MGR, e.HIREDATE
   , e.SAL, e.COMM, e.DEPTNO, d.DNAME, d.LOC
FROM EMP e
INNER JOIN DEPT d ON e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO
WHERE e.ENAME = USER;
```

> **[ORA-30353: expression not supported for query rewrite](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/e29250.htm#ORA-30353)**
>
> **Cause:** The select clause referenced UID, USER, ROWNUM, SYSDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, MAXVALUE, a sequence number, a bind variable, correlation variable, a set result,a trigger return variable, a parallel table queue column, collection iterator, etc.
>   **Action:** Remove the offending expression or disable the REWRITE option on the materialized view.

Would the following get you what you want?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_II
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE AS
SELECT e.EMPNO, e.ENAME, e.JOB, e.MGR, e.HIREDATE
   , e.SAL, e.COMM, e.DEPTNO, d.DNAME, d.LOC
FROM EMP e
INNER JOIN DEPT d ON e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO;

CREATE VIEW V_II AS
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE
   , SAL, COMM, DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC
FROM MV_II
WHERE ENAME = USER;
```